# I created a python bind for CS:GO with pyautogui but it doesnt work

Tags: python

I created a simple bind script. It works on IDLE Python but it doesn't work in  CS:GO. Do you know why?

Mayby it must be on background to work?

```
import keyboard
import pyautogui
import time
def EventListen():
    while True:
        try:
            if keyboard.is_pressed('n'):
                pyautogui.press('`')
                pyautogui.typewrite('say EZ')
                pyautogui.press('enter')
                pyautogui.press('`')
                EventListen()
        except:
            EventListen()
EventListen()
```

Comment: I suggest you improve your question, add some examples, some code and make it more clear and add your source code, Have a look here => [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see the need to use `pyautogui` since you are already using `keyboard` which is sufficient to perform the tasks you need. I have made some changes to your code

```py
import time
import keyboard

def EventListen():
    while True:
        try:
            if keyboard.is_pressed('n'):
                keyboard.press('`')
                keyboard.write('say EZ')
                keyboard.press('enter')
                keyboard.press('`')
            elif keyboard.is_pressed('/'): #add something to end the process
                break
        except:
            EventListen()
        time.sleep(0.001)

EventListen()
```

There is no need to call the function in the while loop, as it will anyway be executed infinitely unless you kill the process. I don't see why the script wouldn't run in the background, in fact I am typing this

```
n`say EZ
`
```

using the script. What might be possible is that your previous program ran continuously, causing high CPU usage which might have competed with the game's demand. I recomend you to add a small delay before every iteration of the while loop, in this case I have added 1 ms delay, which will cause significant reduction in CPU usage. I am not sure if that solved your problem as I am unable to reproduce your exact case, let me know if it helped.

**EDIT :** I forgot to mention, I have added another binding of `keyboard.is_pressed('/')` which will make the program break out of the loop and hence terminate it when `/` key is pressed. You can change this as you like. If you don't want any other binding as such (which I don't recommend) then you can rely on manually killing the task.

Comment: Can you tell me how to make this script work on background and how to kill it after using?

Comment: You can just run the script as you normally do and it will continue to run in the background unless killed. In order to kill it, you can terminate the task directly or use a key binding like I did.

Comment: Thanks, your answer is best, but i need one more info. Does it make sense to convert this to EXE by pyinstaller?

Comment: I don't understand what problem are you exactly facing in running it in background. Using `pyinstaller` would basically package your script with python interpreter into a binary which can be executed, which is no different form you running the script directly since you have python installed in your system. It would only make sense if you wanted to distribute your script as a program.

Comment: Ok i got it. You helped a lot. Can i give you some kind of like or something? ( i am new)

Comment: You can click on the tick mark to accept the answer if it solved your problem and up vote it by clicking the up arrow button above it if deserved. Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

you should make an exe with pyinstaller and you run it background

Comment: It would be better if you could add an explanation as to why the script can't run in the background and the need to pack it into an exe.